# How to enable android's Status LED or change its color?

Tags: android

I searched about it but I can't figure this out!!

There are a few answers but they are not working in **Android 8.0** or above.

I saw this feature in *Alibaba* and *WhatsApp*!!

Help if you can! This can help others too.

**My Codes:**

```
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(0xff0000);
            channel.shouldShowLights();
            channel.canShowBadge();
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "0")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notification))
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 1000, 200,1000 })
            .setChannelId(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setLights(Color.RED, 100 , 100)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


        if (notificationManager != null) {
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
            notification.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
            notification.ledOnMS = 100;
            notification.ledOffMS = 100;
            notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(60000), notification);
        }
```

Comment: One possible issue I see is your `channel.setLightColor()` is not including the A in ARGB. You could try changing that to a `Color.RED` as you are doing lower, or `0xffff0000`.

Comment: @dharms  public static final int RED         = 0xFFFF0000

Comment: Yes, but you aren't using RED. You have `channel.setLightColor(0xff0000);`

Comment: @dharms Its still not working with or without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated codes so i should remove these:

```
        notification.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledOnMS = 100;
        notification.ledOffMS = 100;
```

And replaced **IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT** to **IMPORTANCE_MAX** like below

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), 
remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
```

And like @tyzj's answer and @dharms comment i added this with alpha color:

```
channel.enableLights(true);
channel.setLightColor(0xffff0000)
```

And changed

```
.setLights(Color.RED, 100 , 100)
```

To

```
.setLights(0xffff0000, 1000 , 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

enable lights in the channel

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#enableLights(boolean)